# How to write code in Rails to run my desired query in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm making a chat room app in Rails and I have 3 tables as follows:

- Users `id`, `name`
- Rooms `id`, `user_id`, `title`
- Participants `id`, `room_id`, `user_id`

`users` and `rooms` have the following associations.

```rb
# user.rb
has_many :rooms
```

```rb
# room.rb
belongs_to :user
```

I want to be able to show the list of names of participants by writing:

```rb
# rooms/show.html.erb
<% @participants.each do |participant| %>
  <%= participant.user.name %>
<% end %>
```

In my controller, I have tried:

```rb
# rooms_controller.rb
def show
  @participants = Participant.includes(:users).where(room_id: 1)
end
```

But I get an error saying `Association named 'users' was not found on Participant; perhaps you misspelled it?`.
I have a feeling that setting associations between `users` and `participants` would might solve the problem, but I'm not sure what their relations are. (It's not a simple `has_many`/`belongs_to` relation, is it...?)

Overall, I want to run a SQL query that's something like `SELECT * FROM participants INNER JOIN users ON participants.user_id = users.id WHERE participants.room_id = 1`. How can I write in Rails to run this query?

Answer (score 0):

I think the relation between `User` and `Room` is a many-to-many. Then, use `:has_and_belongs_to_many`:

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association

But if you want to set the relation between `User` and `Participant` as many-to-many, use option `:through`:

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

I think, a table `Participant` is not required, just a temporary variable `participants` seems ok.

Answer (score 0):

Your `participant` model does have an association name `users`.

You can set up a `has many through` association like this:

```
# room.rb
belongs_to :user
has_many :participants
has_many :users, through: :participants
```

so in your controller you can get users of a room:

```
room = Room.find(1)
users = room.users
```